# Is it possible to access outer variables inside JAVA8 stream filter?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, filter, java-stream

I am stuck on a senario where I want to filter 20% of the elements inside a ArrayList of string based on a condition. I searched for Stream.filter and there is something that holds me from using it. 
I have a arraylist containig string as "one,two,three,four" and a match variable String match = "e"; Assuming I already have the list as myList, I want to do something like,

```
public List<String> filterArrayList(List<String> myList, String match){
    List<String> filtered_result=myList.stream().filter(elem -> {
    if(elem.indexOf(match)!=-1){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return filtered_result; 
}
filterArrayList(somelist,"e");
```

But this seems to not work as I am not able to access match variable inside filter. It just returns the list as "e" which is the value of the variable match.
      filtered_result = ["e"]

I also tried doing this,

```
List<String> filtered_result=myList.stream().filter(elem -> elem.contains(match)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this also returns the same. Is there any way I can do a work around here ?

PS : I dont want to create a POJO class just for this purpose nor can I create a final variable as the list comes as an argument to this method that is being my many methods across classes.

EDIT : The match variable that is mapped to the method can vary from method to method and it cannot stay the same.

Comment: I don't understand your edits, but final parameters... `public List<String> filterArrayList(final List<String> myList, final String match)`, do not affect the external values of the objects.

Comment: just mark your `String match` parameter with `final`.

Comment: Your problem description doesn’t make the slightest sense. First, you are saying “I am not able to access match variable inside filter”, then you’re saying “It just returns the list as "e" which is the value of the variable match”. Where is the connection between these two statements? Besides that, you are storing the result in a variables named `filtered_result`, but are referring to a variables named `filtered_list`, which doesn’t appear anywhere else in the code you have shown. Perhaps, that’s the entire problem, who knows.

Comment: @cricket_007 the original version didn’t even have a method/function declaration around the code, still it was inconsistently referring to `filtered_result` and `filtered_list` and, more importantly, containing these contradicting statements about not being able to do the operation at all and about getting an unintended “result”.

Comment: @MikeRoss Don’t blame others for your inability to ask an understandable question. You have accepted an answer that contains exactly the same code that you posted in your question, containing only minor differences (besides not having the typo), so what was your problem? Neither of your contradicting problem descriptions, “not able to access match variable inside filter” nor “It just returns the list as "e"”, applies to your code. The typo was only an *additional* contradiction. As clearly said in the previous comments which were *not* centered around the typo.

Comment: @Holger I never asked you specifically to help me out. If you dont understand the problem that way I put it, I suggest you get the hell out this question. Please dont blame a newbie to score comments and values in a forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show this works as written in a method, here's that approach

```
public static List<String> matchFilter(List<String> list, final String match) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.indexOf(match) != -1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String match = "e";
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
    System.out.println(matchFilter(myList, match)); // [one, three]
}
```

You should probably try printing out the content of `myList` before applying the stream filtering

Regarding the extra comments.

> I dont want to create a POJO class just for this purpose

You don't need to, but that's a utility method, so it can be off in some random class as a `static` method, to be used anywhere.

> nor can I create a final variable as the list comes as an argument to this method that is being my many methods across classes

As shown in this code, `final String match` is a valid parameter. It doesn't need to be final, but I am showing that it doesn't affect anything. The List could also be final, but there's no reason here. Making any variable final only means you cannot *reassign* it. *You can still add and remove values* to a `final List`.

<sub>Note: This is filtering 50%, not 20% (which isn't possible in a list of 4 elements)</sub>

Comment: “The List could also be final, but there's no reason here”—the same applies to the `match` parameter; the presence of the `final` modifier at that parameter variable doesn’t make any difference to what the OP did. The actual main difference is that you are not referring to either, `filtered_result` nor `filtered_list`, avoiding that inconsistency. In the end, nobody knows what the OP’s actual problem is (especially the mysterious `filtered_list = ["e"]` “result”)…

Answer (score 0):

To use the variable `match` in the lambda it must be *effectively `final`* (and it is here and in your example). Your first example works here, but it's inelegant; the problem must be in how you get `myList` - Instead of an `if` just `return elem.indexOf(match) != -1;` - which can be further refined as in this mcve,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String match = "e";
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
    List<String> filtered_result = myList.stream() //
            .filter(e -> e.indexOf(match) != -1) //
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(filtered_result);
}
```

Which outputs

```
[one, three]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but sorry I forgot to mention, the match string also comes as an argument to this method. I am looking for a solution to filter dynamically using dynamic conditions.

Comment: @MikeRoss The scope of `match` shouldn't matter, whether it's a parameter, local variable, or even a field.

Comment: @cricket_007 the value for match changes from method and its not a fixed values. the value is kind of stored in db and based on whatever value is stored in db, this needs to be called.

Comment: @MikeRoss So? If you think that is a problem, then show that in the question as a complete example. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for filtering out based on  'match' variables value from your list? If yes then the code below should help you

```
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    String match = "e";
    List<String> result = lines.stream()               
            .filter(line -> !match.equals(line))    
            .collect(Collectors.toList());             
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
```